# React default function

Tags: reactjs

I am discovering React and I am wondering. The default function renders the html. However, let's say I want to create different function within the default function, how does this work? Like I would like to have the default function (adminDashboard), with two actual functions in it (one for  showHeader, and another one for a ShowButton). How would I structure it in order for it to render?

here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

function AdminDashboard() {

return 
   <ShowActionBtns/>;
   <Header/>;


}

function ShowActionBtns (){
return(
    <div className='bg-dark text-white py-4'>
          <div className='container'>
        <div className='row'>
            <div className='col-md-6'>
                <h1>
                    <i className='fas fa-home'>   home</i>
                </h1>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

function Header (){
return(
    <div className='bg-dark text-white py-4'>
          <div className='container'>
        <div className='row'>
            <div className='col-md-6'>
                <h1>
                    <i className='fas fa-home'>   home</i>
                </h1>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 )
}

export default AdminDashboard;
```

Comment: "The default function renders the html" - thats incorrect, you decide what renders the HTML when you import the component, ie you can have named imports (without default import) and still render the components.

Comment: ok in my case I have an adminDashboard component. I would like to have several function (header, button, table) within that component. what is the best practice? To create those function and then render them at the end ? I am a bit confused as tp what the default function does.

Comment: There is no such thing "default function", `export default` is JS syntax, see MDN link in my answer. And asking about "best practice" is discouraged in StackOverflow since its opinion based. Go through React docs and see recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to export the other components.

> Notice that custom components names [should be capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#specifying-the-react-element-type).

```
export default function AdminDashboard() {...}
export const ShowActionBtns = () => {...}

// Usage
import AdminDashboard, {ShowActionBtns} from './Components.js'

// Same, just both named imports
export function AdminDashboard() {...}
export const ShowActionBtns = () => {...}

// Usage
import {AdminDashboard, ShowActionBtns} from './Components.js'
```

See [`export` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Comment: OK, but can I do that for instance. I edited the post you can see above.